# Не работает UILongPressGestureRecognizer у WKWebView

Tags: webview, swift4, uigesturerecognizer

В моём *view* есть два *subview*: **WKWebView** (webView) и **MediaPlayer** (player.view)

Сначала идёт плеер, а поверх него открывается браузер с интерфейсом для плеера.
Мне нужно реализовать долгое нажатие по экрану, чтобы хотя бы появилось обычное сообщение, но у меня это не выходит.

Прошу, подскажите в чём проблема?

Код:

```
override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        let config = webViewConfiguration()
        webView = WKWebView(frame: self.view.bounds, configuration: config)
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(webView)
    }

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let longPressRecognizer = UILongPressGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(ViewController.longPressed(gestureRecognizer:)))
        longPressRecognizer.delegate = self
        webView.addGestureRecognizer(longPressRecognizer)
    }

func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRequireFailureOf otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func longPressed(gestureRecognizer: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
        if gestureRecognizer.state == .began {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: nil, message: "longPressed", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
            alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
            print("hello")
        }
    }
```

Ещё есть отдельный метод, который весь я писать не буду, но там добавляется *subview* медиаплеера вот такой строкой: `view.insertSubview(player.view, belowSubview: webView)`

В заголовок класса добавлено `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Стало работать после внесения небольшой корректировки в эту функцию:

```
func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith otherGestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```